# Drivative question

Tags: derivatives

> Real variables $x$ and $y$ satisfy the relation $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{x^3}{y^2}$ and we know that the value of $y^3$ is $-9$ when the value of $x$ is $2$. What is the value of $x^2$ when the value of $y$ is $3$?
>
> (a) $5$
>
> (b) $6$
>
> (c) $8$
>
> (d) $12$

I tried finding the change in $y$ as $3-9^{\frac{1}{3}}$ but there is got to be a simpler method to solve this!

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: How did you find $3-9^{\frac13}$?

Answer (score 3):

$$y^2dy=x^3dx$$

Integrate both sides  $$\dfrac{y^3}3=\dfrac{x^4}4+K$$ where $K$ is an arbitrary constant

Put $x=2,y^3=-9$  to find $K$